# Khmer Rouge Property Rights Destruction

Tags: contemporary-history, south-east-asia, titles

Did Khmer Rouge actually destroy **all** land titles/ownership records? Or were there certain regions that happened to escape this destruction? If so, is there any documentation on where these regions were?

Comment: Why would you question the narrative? They sought to destroy all records; what leads you to believe that they failed to do so?

Comment: Most things aren't absolute. Failure in this goal could be due to a whole host of reasons.